# how to pass pointers as parameters in a function?

Tags: c, function, pointers, definition

I am trying to print the sum and diffrence of numbers using pointers but i am getting only sum as output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void update(int *a,int *b)

 {

    int sum,sub;

    sum = *a + *b;

    printf("",sum);

    sub = abs(*a - *b);

    printf("",sub);

}

int main()

{

    int a, b;

    int *pa = &a, *pb = &b;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    update(pa, pb);
    printf("%d\n%d", a, b); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("",sum);` forgot to write `%d\n` by any chance?

Comment: Also, that function is not changing the values of `a` and `b` so I don't know what you would expect from that last `printf` call except printing the exact same values as the first one. Maybe you forgot to update the values in the `update` function? Looks strange.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly (taking into account the function name) you mean something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void update( int *a, int *b )
{
    *a += *b;
    *b = abs( *a - *b - *b );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a, b;

    scanf( "%d%d", &a, &b );

    update( &a, &b );

    printf( "a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b );

    return 0;
}
```

If for example to enter two values `20` and `10` then the output will look like

```
a = 30, b = 10
```

Pay attention to that these calls of `printf` in your function

```
printf("",sum);

printf("",sub);
```

do not make sense.

Comment: I figured it out . The code should be as follow, in the update function ;sum=*a;sub=*b;    i have just started to code , so pardon silly mistakes